# After updating my Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04 Gnome Terminal is showing Unicode Characters?How to fix that?

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, gnome-shell, gnome-panel, unicode

[image: Gnome terminal]
Screenshot Of Gnome terminal after updating to 20.04.

Comment: Open Preferences and choose a different font.

Comment: Thanks @egmont. That solved the problem for me.

Comment: Hi @egmont, can you convert your comment into an answer so we can "solve" this question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Preferences -> Unnamed -> Text->Custom font ;
change none font to any font

and

You may also find the following useful to change the default font rendering:

```
  $ dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig-config

  $ dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig
```